# chmod 001 or 111? Unix Permissions for executable files question

Tags: permissions, chmod

I am confused as to what this question is asking me to do. For context, hello is a c++ file.

> "Use chmod command again to make hello an executable, but not readable
>   and not writeable for all users."

Using an online chmod calculator, my best guess would be `chmod 001 hello`, which is executable by the public, but not readable nor writeable by the public.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all allow me to explain the basics of chmod.

Chmod is a Unix command that allows you to set permissions that determine who can access the file, and how they can access it.

You can set these permissions for 3 different categories.

1. The owner of the file (**U**ser)
2. The members of the group that owns that file (**G**roup)
3. Everyone else (**O**thers)

There are two ways to modify the permissions:

**1) By using alphanumeric characters**

The permissions are separated in 3 categories:

a. **R**ead 
 b. **W**rite 
 c. e**X**ecute

You can set the permissions in the following way:
Let's imagine a file called `file.sh`
We want to set the permissions so that

- the user can **r**ead, **w**rite, e**x**ecute
- the group can **r**ead, **w**rite
- the others can **r**ead

All we have to do is run

```
chmod u=rwx,g=rw,o=r file.sh
```

Or perhaps we want to make it executable to everyone, so we run

```
chmod +x file.sh
```

and if want the opposite of the above command we can do

```
chmod -x file.sh
```

**2) By using octal numbers**

The other way is by using octal numbers that each one of them represent the permissions for the user, group, and others, in that order.

- 4 stands for "read"
- 2 stands for "write"
- 1 stands for "execute"
- 0 stands for "no permissions."

By adding those numbers we can easily set the individual permissions. So if we take the previous example that would mean

```
chmod 764 file.sh
```

7 is the result of permissions 4+2+1, 6 is 4+2+0 and 4 is 4+0+0

**You can view more information by running `man chmod`**

---

Back to your problem. Although your question is unclear I would say you should use

```
chmod 711 hello
```

Which means you (the owner) have full permissions, your group can only execute and same goes for everyone else.

or (depending on how you interpret the words *"all users"*)

```
chmod 771 hello
```

Which means you (the owner) have full permissions, same goes for your group but everyone else can only execute.

Now I should mention that you could use something like

```
chmod 001 hello
```

or

```
chmod 111 hello
```

but I see no point on doing something like this, unless it's a compiled program or something. But still...

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't exactly clear but my guess would be they want something like 771 or any combination of nn1.  However I don't think 001 is exactly what they are looking for.  They only specify that **all users** should be able to execute not not read or write, so there is no reason that the owner/group shouldn't be able to read/write.

Additionally if you *did* set the permissions to 001 **you** would not be able to execute, so therefore at the very least they want 111.